# Changing limits order

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_{n,m}$ a double sequence such that

- $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ $\lim_m a_{n,m}$ exist $(a_{n,m})_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$ is non-decreasing.
- $\forall m\in \mathbb{N}$ $\lim_n a_{n,m} = l$ exist and doesn't depend on $m$.

Is it possible to show with these assumptions that $\lim_n\lim_m a_{n,m} = \lim_m\lim_n a_{n,m} = l$.

The only thing i can easily see is that $$\liminf_n \lim_m a_{n,m} \geq l $$

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, consider

$$\begin{matrix}0&0&0&0&0& .&.&.\\1&0&0&0&0& .&.&.\\1&1&0&0&0& .&.&.&\\1&1&1&0&0& .&.&.&\\1&1&1&1&0& .&.&.&\\.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.\end{matrix}$$